# Regex for a string between a string and a newline

Tags: regex

Okay, I have read for a few hours and can't get my regex to work.  **I can't use groups** or process the returning text in anyway, so it has to pull the right thing the first time.

I need to pull the serial number from this text:

```
Hardware Version                   : 0600
Serial Number                      : FOC145183BA
Product ID                         : CTS-CODEC-PRI-G2
```

I have tried: `(Serial Number.*[:])(.*)`
But this gives me "Serial Number" to the end of the text.  I have tried the ? thing, but it just errored.  I am using this through telnet to a cisco codec and it is not giving me any flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for that edit. I didn't realize at first how it cut it out.

Comment: What regex version? Very different `sed` vs `Perl`

Comment: Not sure, I am using Pexpect, a Python module.  I looked through the docs and it only mentions it accepts regex, but not how it compiles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without groups this may be impossible, but if you are allowed substitution then you could try something weird like

```
s/^Serial Number\s*:\s*$|^[^S].*$//g
```

Removing the start of the line and any other line not starting with S. Not amazingly elegant but may get the job done

Comment: This did it, but you are right, it is very confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing special characters to force "zero or more", which is `*`, or "one or more", which is `+`, in your attempts. Try `Serial Number.*: (.+)$` .

Answer (score 0):

The result is captured in the first group (\1)

```
Serial Number\s*:\s*(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the regex engine and whether greedy etc

```
(Serial Number.*[:])(.*)$
```

Dollar should match end of line, but in some engines might match end of the pattern space if it is in some multi line processing mode